# Capture front-facing camera - Phonegap?

Tags: ios, api, cordova, camera, capture

How to capture video from front-facing camera, using Phonegap?

I found this `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});` in Phonegaps API docs online. But I dont see anything about using the front camera instead of rear. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think after the camera opens up, u can choose the front camera. Currently i dont think so there is an option to open the front camera by default

Answer (score 1):

If your smartphone have front and back camera, when you use

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

capture camera will be opened with switch button automatically.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark as Answer for the other members (10x).

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with PhoneGap today since I had an idea for an app. For this idea I needed the front facing camera aswell to be selected as default. After trying different things I found a work around which selected the front facing camera by default [**NOTE**: this is a dirty fix, I've got no clue what happens on devices without a front facing camera!]

In Xcode (or whatever editor you use) open `[ProjectName]/plugins/CDVCapture.m` and locate both captureImage and captureVideo. Both functions/commands have a line saying

`pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`

Add this line below:

`pickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;`

And both Video and Image capturing will select the front facing camera by default when opening up the camera app. However, the user still has the possibility to switch cameras.

Here's a pastebin with my full CVDCapture.m file: http://pastebin.com/kkkyiPdn